# Convert .p12 file to .pem using Terminal app in Mac "No such file or directory" error?

Tags: iphone, ios, terminal, pem, pkcs#12

I have export the "Apple Development IOS Push Service" certificate from Keychain Access and save the "apns-dev-cert.p12" in my desktop. I want to enable `Apple Push Notification` I have followed these blogs to convert `apns-dev-cert.p12 to apns-dev-cert.pem` from Terminal app,

```
http://bhaveshkumbhani.blogspot.in/2011/12/convert-p12-to-pem-for-apns.html
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
Apple Document RemoteNotificationPG.pdf
```

I have used these commands in Terminal,

```
    1.V******-Ms-iMac-2:~ c*****$ openssl pkcs12 -in apns-dev-cert.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
        Response : Error opening input file apns-dev-cert.p12
        Certificates.p12: No such file or directory
    2.V******-Ms-iMac-2:~ c*****$ openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out apns-dev-cert.pem -in apns-dev-cert.p12
        Response : Error opening input file apns-dev-cert.p12
        Certificates.p12: No such file or directory
    3.V******-Ms-iMac-2:~ c*****$ ls
            All_iOS_Applications_Document.doc   Pictures
            AppStoreSubmissionSteps.doc     Public
            Desktop                 Sites
            Documents               Softwares
            Downloads               Untitled.txt
            Dropbox                 pic
            Library                 pic.zip
            Movies                  pricelist.txt
            Music                   sms.txt
            Nana_User_Case_Documents.odt
   4. V******-Ms-iMac-2:~ c*****$ cd
   5.V******-Ms-iMac-2:~ c*****$ cd/Users/c*****/Desktop/A
-bash: cd/Users/c*****/Desktop/A: No such file or directory
```

I can't understand why the terminal always saying "No such file or directory"?. Where i need to save the .p12 file in my Mac?

Am using `Terminal app Version 2.1.2 (273.1). Mac OS X version 10.6.8`.

Can you please what i need to do? I need to enable the APNS by using the .pem file. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I have added tried Raywenderlich.com termial code in my mac Terminal app

```
1. V******-Ms-iMac-2:~ c*****$ pwd
/Users/creagx
2. V******-Ms-iMac-2:~ c*****$ cd/ Users/creagx/Desktop/A
-bash: cd/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: R u following rayWenderLich tutorial?

Comment: Yes i am following the tutorial. I have tried their steps to create .pem file but it's not working for me.

Comment: Have you changed to the right Directory? Type "pwd" to check where you are.

Comment: you are missing a space between cd and /Users

Comment: Hello Mr.Maffo Thanks for your response. I have edited my question that i have tried your words in Terminal. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Type in:

```
cd /Users/creagx/Desktop/A (Space between cd and Slash: cd[SPACE]/Users/creagx/Desktop/A
```

if there is a Folder named "A" on your Desktop where the p12 files are in.

Then go on with the other Commands

`openssl pkcs12 -in apns-dev-cert.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts`

`openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out apns-dev-cert.pem -in apns-dev-cert.p12`

Comment: The 2 commands are exactly similar. They're working well though. These are the correct commands.

Comment: for what it's worth, the 2 commands aren't exactly similar. The second one doesn't export the private key along with it and that is needed at least for django-push-notifications which is what I was using