# Converting PEM file to P12

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, iphone-developer-program

I was able to convert P12 certificate to PEM file using the terminal commands written here:

[Convert .p12 file to .pem using Terminal app in Mac "No such file or directory" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412603/convert-p12-file-to-pem-using-terminal-app-in-mac-no-such-file-or-directory)

I want to manage the certificate on the cloud which accepts only pem files. So is there a similar terminal command which converts .pem to .p12 so that it can be installed on the Mac Keychain once downloaded from the cloud.

Steps I wanted to replicate:

1. Take the p12 from Keychain Access and convert into .pem file.
2. Upload the pem file onto cloud certificate manager for storing it.
3. Give the access to developers to download the .pem file for signing the iOS App.
4. Developer will download the .pem file and convert it into .p12 file, double click the .p12 and install it into their Keychain Access.

Comment: maybe this can help https://code.google.com/archive/p/apns-sharp/wikis/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate.wiki

Comment: The process mentioned in the link is combining cer and private key into p12. That's not I intend to do. Edited the question for better understanding the question.